# Styling in react getting error as 'width' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am doing my react project to create side navigation bar.

So I have this button on clicking that button side side navigation bar should open.

```
<button className="openbtn" onClick={(e) => openNav(e)}>&#9776; Open Sidebar</button>
```

This is my **openNav** function

```
  function openNav() {
    console.log("open nav")
    document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementsByClassName("test").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }
```

When I am doing that  I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined
```

my sidenav styles looks like

```
 .sidenav {
     margin-top: 50px;
    height:100%;
    width: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
```

In css file both sidenav and test has width property.

So how to solve this?

This works in normal html/css/javascript how to do it in react ?

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing direct DOM manipulation in React like this, but can you include the component that has a `sidenav` class assigned in it? `document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")` I believe should be returning an array of elements with that classname.

Answer (score 1):

Using `getElementsByClassName()`, you are referring to the collection. Specify the first number in the array as **[0]**. Try this code:

```
function openNav() {
    console.log("open nav")
    document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")[0].style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
```

Comment: Thats typo sorry

Comment: @bad_coder9042093, Do not worry. We all make typos sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")` is `HTMLCollection`. You need to iterate for each element and assign style for them.

```
let sideNav = document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")
for(let i = 0; i < sideNav.length; i++)
   sideNav[i].style.width = "250px"
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName`return more than one elements. So, you can't just write`.style.width`. Instead you need to run the loop.

```js
const navEl = document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")
for (var i = 0; i < navEl.length; i++) {
    navEl[i].style.width= "250px";
}
```

Or you're just interested in one element, go with

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")[0].style.width= "250px"
```

Finally, you've typo in question as `getElementsByClassNamed("test")`. An extra `d` after `ClassName`.